# How do I print out numbers in ascending order in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to print out something like this:

```
1: *****

2: ****

3: ***

4: ******
```

The code I already have prints out the asterisks and the colon but I'm not sure how to make it print out the ascending order of numbers at the left side.When I take in a list of numbers the code prints out the number of asterisks based on each element in the list. What I can't do is print out the numbers on the left which is basically saying what the position of the number of asterisks in the list is. I've tried printing the head of a list `[1..10]` and then recursing it with `xs` of `(x:xs)` but it still gives me errors.

This is the code I already have:

```
printPattern :: Int -> Char -> [String]
printPattern len a = map (take len . cycle) [[a]]

printStars :: Int -> IO()
printStars x = mapM_ putStrLn (printPattern x '*')

displayGame :: [Int] -> IO(Int)
displayGame (x:xs) = do putStr " : "
                        printStars x
                        displayGame xs
```

Comment: What errors does it give? For recursion, you need a base case.

Comment: What do the number of askerisks have to do with the numbers in front?

Answer (score 1):

```
displayGame :: [Int] -> IO ()
displayGame xs = for_ (zip [1..] xs) $ \(i, x) ->
  putStr $ show i ++ ": " ++ replicate x '*' ++ "\n\n"
```

Comment: which part of my code do i replace with this? Is it just the displayGame function or all of it?

Comment: @ChongJenFoong, with what error message. What might that error mean?

Comment: Look at hoogle.haskell.org to help navigate your way around the libraries